# Implementing SSL for SharePoint High trust Apps

Tags: sharepoint, iis, web-applications, ssl, sharepoint-2013

I have been struggling to configure an SSL Certificate based environment for hight trust apps in SharePoint 2013. I have on-premises installation of SharePoint 2013 (Enterprise). Following google and msdn articles, I figured out that high trust apps require Client SSL authentication. My app is a provider hosted app and requires an "https" url to be hit when triggered (there is no option for setting "http" url). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Kirk Evans' blog post on the subject to get you started:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/11/27/creating-high-trust-sharepoint-apps-with-microsoft-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-preview-2.aspx

I was able to walk through this to get 90% to where I needed to be, *including* creation of a self-signed certificate for the PHA server.

What Kirk's blog *didn't* cover for me:

1. **Setting up a dedicated PHA server**. Kirk's post finishes with running the app
   from IIS Express inside Visual Studio. I wound up needing a modified
   web.config for non-dev builds, i.e. for code deployed to a dedicated
   IIS instance.
2. **Setting up for App lifecycle event receivers**. If you want to handle
   App lifecycle events from your PHA, then you may have even more
   tweaking to do in the web.config file. To this point I've had to
   enable Anonymous authentication in my service bindings in web.config
   in order for SharePoint to call those handlers.

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this for bindings :
http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html
and In the publishing profile, modify the "SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish" and the "publishUrl"
SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish --> `https://YourServerName:PortNumber/VistualDirectoryFolderName`
& publishUrl --> Path where you publish your web

before this uncheck the "Use IIS Express" from your provider hosted web properties and select "Use local IIS web server". Pass the address of your simple `http://YourServerName:PortNumber/..` url and create virtual directory.